# Choosing a clip gradient for LSTM (DeepAR)

Tags: neural-networks, lstm

I'm training DeepAR using the GluonTS library. I was getting NAN loss after some time of training (similar to this problem here: https://github.com/awslabs/gluon-ts/issues/833).

It worked for me to lower the clip gradient but this was trial and error. The default is 10 (in the GluonTS library) and I ended up using 1.

I have two questions.

1. How should I choose the clip gradient (other than through trial
   and error)?
2. Is there any downside to use glip gradient of 1 instead of 10? If not, why shouldn't I always start with 1 instead of the default of 10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How should I choose the clip gradient (other than through trial and error)?

You won't know ahead of time if a gradient step takes you to a location on the loss surface where the loss is NaN. Trial and error is the only way.

> Is there any downside to use glip gradient of 1 instead of 10? If not, why shouldn't I always start with 1 instead of the default of 10?

A smaller gradient clip size means that the farthest distance each gradient step can travel is smaller. This could mean that you need to take more gradient steps to reach a minimum. But, as you've discovered, choosing a gradient clipping size that's too large could mean that the loss becomes NaN.

Finding the "Goldilocks zone" between too-small and too-large is the key. Where this zone is will depend on the network and the data.